# Pesquisa em php não retorna os resultados corretamente

Tags: php

Estou com um problema referente ao retorno das informações do banco de dados em php, tenho duas tabelas, uma tb_regiao, com os estados brasileiros e outra, tb_representante com os representantes em cada estado.

Abaixo é a parte com o select:

```
 <form class="ajs-form-representante" method="GET" action="pesquisar_representantes_art_ferro_moveis_fibra_sintetica.php">
            <select type="text" name="pesquisar" >
                <option class="lista-cidade" value="" selected="selected">Escolha a Região</option>
                <?php require_once ("ajs-script-php/selecta_cidade.php");?>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="BUSCAR">
        </form>
```

O script para selecionar a região é esse abaixo:

```
<?php
require_once("ajs-adm/conexao/conecta.php");

$pesqu = $_GET["pesquisar"];
$listar = $conexao->prepare('SELECT * FROM tb_regiao WHERE regiao LIKE "%'.$pesqu.'%" LIMIT 27');
$listar->execute();
while ($exibe = $listar->fetch()){
    $nome_cidade = utf8_encode($exibe['regiao']);
    $nome_id = utf8_encode($exibe['id_id_reg']);
    echo "<option  class='$nome_id'>$nome_cidade</option>";
}
```

O código da pagina para exibir o resultado é esse abaixo:

```
        <section class="ajs-section-rs-a">
            <?php
                $pesquisar = $_GET['pesquisar'];
                $result_repres = "SELECT * FROM tb_representante WHERE estado LIKE '%".$pesquisar."%' LIMIT 1";
                $result_resul_repres = mysqli_query($conect, $result_repres);
                   while($rows_repres = mysqli_fetch_array($result_resul_repres)){
                       echo "<p><b>Representante:</b> ".utf8_encode($rows_repres['nome_rp'])."</p>";
                       echo "<p><b>E-mail:</b> ".utf8_encode($rows_repres['email'])."</p>";
                       echo "<p><b>Celular:</b> ".utf8_encode($rows_repres['cel_a'])."</p>";
                       echo "<p><b>Celular:</b> ".utf8_encode($rows_repres['cel_b'])."</p>";
                       echo "<p><b>Telefone Fixo:</b> ".utf8_encode($rows_repres['tel_fixo'])."</p>";
                       echo "<p><b>Empresa:</b> ".utf8_encode($rows_repres['nome_empresa'])."</p>";
                       echo "<p><b>Endereço:</b> ".utf8_encode($rows_repres['rua'])."</p>";
                       echo "<p><b>Bairro:</b> ".utf8_encode($rows_repres['bairro'])."</p>";
                       echo "<p><b>Cidade:</b> ".utf8_encode($rows_repres['cidade'])."</p>";
                       echo "<p><b>Cep:</b> ".utf8_encode($rows_repres['cep'])."</p>";
                       echo "<p><b>Estado:</b> ".utf8_encode($rows_repres['estado'])."</p>";
                   }
            ?>
        </section>
```

abaixo é a tabela tb_regiao:

```
--

CREATE TABLE `tb_regiao` (
  `id_reg` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_id_reg` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `regiao` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `tb_regiao`
--

INSERT INTO `tb_regiao` (`id_reg`, `id_id_reg`, `regiao`) VALUES
(1, '1', 'Acre'),
(2, '2', 'Alagoas'),
(3, '3', 'Amapá'),
(4, '4', 'Amazonas'),
(5, '5', 'Bahia'),
(6, '6', 'Ceará'),
(7, '7', 'Distrito Federal'),
(8, '8', 'Espírito Santo'),
(9, '9', 'Goiás'),
(10, '10', 'Maranhão'),
(11, '11', 'Mato Grosso'),
(12, '12', 'Mato Grosso do Sul'),
(13, '13', 'Minas Gerais'),
(14, '14', 'Pará'),
(15, '15', 'Paraíba'),
(16, '16', 'Paraná'),
(17, '17', 'Pernambuco'),
(18, '18', 'Piauí'),
(19, '19', 'Rio de Janeiro'),
(20, '20', 'Rio Grande do Norte'),
(21, '21', 'Rio Grande do Sul'),
(22, '22', 'Rondônia'),
(23, '23', 'Roraima'),
(24, '24', 'Santa Catarina'),
(25, '25', 'São Paulo'),
(26, '26', 'Sergipe'),
(27, '27', 'Tocantins');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `tb_regiao`
--
ALTER TABLE `tb_regiao`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_reg`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `tb_regiao`
--
ALTER TABLE `tb_regiao`
  MODIFY `id_reg` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=28;COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

E abaixo é a tabela tb_representante:

```
--

CREATE TABLE `tb_representante` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_id_reg` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `nome_rp` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `nome_one` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `nome_two` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `nome_three` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `nome_empresa` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `tel_fixo` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `cel_a` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `cel_b` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `rua` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `bairro` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `cidade` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `cep` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `estado` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `tb_representante`
--

INSERT INTO `tb_representante` (`id`, `id_id_reg`, `nome_rp`, `email`, `nome_one`, `nome_two`, `nome_three`, `nome_empresa`, `tel_fixo`, `cel_a`, `cel_b`, `rua`, `bairro`, `cidade`, `cep`, `estado`) VALUES
(1, '9', 'Alamo Manini Representações', 'alamomaninirep@terra.com.br', 'Elaine', 'Ataíde', 'Deivide', 'Alamo Manini Representações', '(62) 3515-1110', '(62) 99945-0318', '(62) 98252-1518', 'Rua 6, nº 370 Quadra E3, Lote 31, Sala 910', 'Empire Center, setor oeste', 'Goiânia', '74.115-070', 'Goiás'),
(2, '5', 'Caires Representações', 'cairesrepresentacoes@hotmail.com', 'Edvando', 'Zilmz', '', 'Caires Representações', '(77) 3441-2728', '(77) 99997-7885', '(77) 99996-3581', 'Praça dr. Nelson Lula, nº 22', 'Centro', 'Brumado', '46100-000', 'Bahia');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `tb_representante`
--
ALTER TABLE `tb_representante`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `tb_representante`
--
ALTER TABLE `tb_representante`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Quando clico para buscar o resultado, é retornado apenas o segundo registro, não mostra o primeiro e nenhum outro.

Comment: pq tem esse `LIMIT 1` no código da pagina para exibir o resultado!?!

Comment: de inicio pensei que fosse necessário para limitar o retorno de um resultado por região, mas fiz outros testes e não influencia nesse tipo

Comment: nesse exemplo que enviei que utilizo, ele retorna o resultado da Bahia correto, mas quando clico em Goiás, ou qualquer outra região, não retorna valor algum

Comment: Se você vai usar um `select` para escolher a região, você pode colocar o valor do `select` já como o id da região, para não ter de dar um `LIKE`.

Comment: vou mudar aqui e testar

Comment: encontrei o erro,  com essa dica sua, no script para selecionar a região, eu coloquei class='$nome_id', quando você escreveu acima, "colocar o valor" eu olhei e alterei para "value='$nome_id'", e pronto, rodou normal, quem quiser usar o código é só alterar que roda 100%

Comment: @AnildoFabianoAlexandre posta como resposta, dessa forma outras pessoas saberão que a pergunta foi resolvida

Comment: obrigado pela dica Denis,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

encontrei o erro, com essa dica sua, no script para selecionar a região, eu coloquei class='$nome_id', quando você escreveu acima, "colocar o valor" eu olhei e alterei para "value='$nome_id'", e pronto, rodou normal, quem quiser usar o código é só alterar que roda 100%`

esse é o script corrigido

```
<?php
require_once("ajs-adm/conexao/conecta.php");

$pesqu = $_GET["pesquisar"];
$listar = $conexao->prepare('SELECT * FROM tb_regiao WHERE regiao LIKE "%'.$pesqu.'%" LIMIT 27');
$listar->execute();
while ($exibe = $listar->fetch()){
    $nome_cidade = utf8_encode($exibe['regiao']);
    $nome_id = utf8_encode($exibe['id_id_reg']);
    echo "<option  value='$nome_id'>$nome_cidade</option>";
}
```